# Como resolver a função de recorrência T(n)=2T (n^1/2) + logn ? Exercício do Livro Cormen cap 4

Tags: c

No livro do Cormen, Cap 4 ele detalha como resolver funcoes de recorrecia (Cap 4). Um dos exercicios pede para resolver. Tentei usando a arvore e a inducao porem nao consegui avancar. Como reduzir os valores de log n e n^1/2 para que possa checar a funcao Big-O?

Comment: Você pode encontrar uma solução em [MATH](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159720/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-tn-2tn-2-n-log-n)

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que o log(n) é na base 2, a solução da função de recorrência fica assim:

```
T(n) = 2*T( sqrt(n) ) + log(n)

Substituindo n = 2^m  
T(2^m) = 2*T( sqrt(2^m) ) + log(2^m)  
T(2^m) = 2*T( 2^(m/2) ) + m
```

Considerando a seguinte transformação:

```
S(m) = T(2^m)  
Temos:  
S(m) = 2*S(m/2) + m
```

Podemos substituir m = 2^x

```
S(2^x) = 2*S( 2^(x-1) ) + 2^x
```

E podemos ir substituindo recursivamente

```
S( 2^(x-1) ) = 2*S( 2^(x-2) ) + 2^(x-1)  
S( 2^(x-2) ) = 2*S( 2^(x-3) ) + 2^(x-2)  
S( 2^(x-3) ) = 2*S( 2^(x-4) ) + 2^(x-3)  
...
```

Obtendo:

```
S(2^x) = 2*[2*[2*[...] + 2^(n-2)] + 2^(n-1)] + 2^n
```

Fazendo até chegar a S(1) e resolvendo o somatório temos:

```
S(2^x) = 2^x*S(1) + x*2^x  
Como S(1) = 1  
S(2^x) = 2^x + x*2^x
```

Substituindo n = 2^x

```
S(n) = n + log(n)*n
```

Essa é a solução da função de recorrência `S(n) = 2*S(n/2) + n` que é isomórfica à função que queremos pela transformação `S(n)=T(2^n)`

Portanto substituindo

```
S(m) = T(2^m)  
T(2^m) = S(m) = m + log(m)*m
```

E finalmente substituindo n = 2^m temos:

```
m = log(n)

T(n) = log(n) + log( log(n) )*log(n)
```

Essa é a solução da função de recorrência dada e portanto ela tem a seguinte complexidade:

```
O(T(n)) = log(n) * log( log(n) )
```

Comment: S(1) = 1 foi escolhido como valor inicial, que equivale a T(2)=1, mas para qualquer outro valor o raciocínio é o mesmo e a complexidade também.